# Select Multiple Columns from XML Type column in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xmltype

I have used XML column for store data which can have dynamic nodes and attributes i.e. a Account node can have N number of nodes, I would like to retrieve those all nodes in single select query as multiple columns i.e. Col1, Col2, Col3 etc.

I tried below query but its returning vertical rows, I would like to have horizontal rows. Below is expected output. Col1, Col2 ..Nth Col

```
TAX-1 Amount|TAX-2 Amount|TAX-3 Amount...Nth Columns
1232        |4050        |57
```

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML='<Info>
   <Demand>
      <Tax ID="1">
         <Head>1232</Head>
         <Int>10</Int>
         <OtherFee>5</OtherFee>        
      </Tax>
      <Tax ID="2">
         <Head>4050</Head>
         <Int>10</Int>
         <OtherFee>5</OtherFee>         
      </Tax>
       <Tax ID="3">
         <Head>57</Head>
         <Int>10</Int>
         <OtherFee>5</OtherFee>         
      </Tax>
    </Demand>
   <Collection>      
      <Tax ID="1">
         <Head>500</Head>
         <Int>10</Int>
         <OtherFee>5</OtherFee>         
      </Tax>
      <Tax ID="2">
         <Head>800</Head>
         <Int>10</Int>
         <OtherFee>5</OtherFee>         
      </Tax>
   </Collection>   
</Info>'
```

Current query which is returning vertical output

```
SELECT T.C.value('Head[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Amount,
T.C.value('@ID', 'varchar(max)') as Head
FROM @XML.nodes('/Info/Demand/Tax') as T(C)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32914)

Any suggestion or input are most welcome!

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: This can be done easily using dynamic pivot technique.